# Case sensitive query in Wakanda db

Tags: wakanda

I am working with an external system that uses case sensitive keys.  To simplify, lets say ID 'a1' and 'A1' represent two different entities.  I need to find the entity by external ID but query and find methods are not case sensitive in Wakanda so it finds both (or possibly wrong) entities when I query/find.  Any Ideas?

```
ds[dataClassName].query("externalID == :1","a1");
```

I want to find one (correct) entity not two as this code does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `sensitiveQuery()` dataclass method that does a `query()` inside and then filter the query result with an `indexOf` and returns the correct entity. A `ds.Prospect.sensitiveQuery()` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in the current implementation of Wakanda, queries are NOT case sensitive.

Fred

Answer (score 0):

I found that the indexOf() method is case sensitive and I have an auto sequenced ID and external ID for each prospect so the following will find the correct entity.  Probably very inefficient.  Any improvements?

```
var x = ds.Prospect.query('externalID == a1');
var i = x.externalID.indexOf('A1');
x[i];
```